# Form Action submit over https

Tags: login, wp-login-form

I am trying to make my website PCI compliant.  It has a login form on top of each page in which the form tag is written like so:

```
<form id="wp_login_form" action="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php', 'https') ?>" method="post">
```

According to wordpress documentation this should print an https url in the action, but it doesn't.  Any idea why or how I should go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, I'd expect to see `https://yoursitename.comwp-login.php`  as a response .  I think you are missing a slash.   `echo site_url('/wp-login.php', 'https')`